# How to get a 3DS file in to a silverlight web application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have created the 3d character with animation by using 3ds Max 2012. Then saved  that max file as 3DS file format. I need to embed this 3DS file into a silverlight web application by using Ab3d.Reader3ds.dll file(3rd party file)
To add this i have to add as a reference into the web project.
But when i tried to add this reference it will show a error message showing as 
  "You can't add a reference to Ab3d.Reader3ds.dll as it was not built against the Silverlight runtime. Silverlight projects will only work with Silverlight assemblies.

I'm using Silverlight version 5 and Visual studio 2010.
If somebody could help me quickly reply me soon. 
If there's another way to do this please reply me with that way.
Thank you.

Comment: Ab3d.Reader3ds was made for native .Net apps, not web-based Silverlight apps. This approach won't work. You need an alternate approach. I can't think of one right now, but when I do, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could find is to switch to the [Babylon engine](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Babylon-3D-engine-f0404ace/view/SourceCode). It is a small download that will allow you to easily use 3D in your Silverlight app. Its supported by Microsoft, so it seems legit. I can't speak from experience, but it seems like it should be what you're looking for. Only problem is, it can only import from Collada and Nova formats. I recommend Collada. Here is a Collada exporter for 3DS max

http://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/OpenCOLLADA#OpenCOLLADA_1.2.2

Good luck!